# Unable to transform feature classes having GCS_WGS_1984 to the current data frame layer (NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize if my question seems too basic. I am designing a map of various locations that are of interest to my organization. I've obtained all of the layers from the City of Burnaby OpenData website. Upon adding them into ArcMap 10.3, I noticed that the feature classes were operating on the GCS_WGS_1984 datum. Given a city like Burnaby (British Columbia, Canada), I reasoned that the current datum distorts the map far too much. I thus changed the data frame to NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N, but the respective feature classes still operated on the GCS_WGS_1984 datum. Did I miss a few steps in between the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap works with on-the-fly transformations.  It is automatically transforming the WGS84 data into the coordinate system of the data frame.

More info:  [On-The_Fly](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/On_the_fly)

If you want to actually re-project your data to a new projection, you need to use the tool "Project".

More info: [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/project.htm)